# autocomplete widget doesnt work for some reason.....(jQuery Autocomplete With MySQL And PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I want to use AUTOCOMPLETE widget from importing JQUERY library, 
but for some reason
 **it doesnt seem to run.**... 
could you help me out with this problem?

What i want to do is to make an auto-suggestion list, something that reads your input and shows related matches extracted from MYSQL as you type.
if you have any thoughts from reading my code, plz let me know as well as the question i asked first.

thank you!!!

---input.php---

```
<body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
    <script language="JavaScript">


                (function($){
                    $(document).ready(function(){


                            $('#customerAutocomplte').autocomplete({

                                    source: function(request, response) {
                                            $.ajax({

                                                url: "./suggest_address.php",


                                                dataType: "json",

                                                type: "post",

                                                data: {
                                                    term : request.term,
                                                },

                                                success: function( data ) {

                                                }
                                            });
                                     },            


                                    minLength:3,

                                    select: function( event, ui ) {


                                        this.form1.prefName.value   = ui.item.prefName;
                                        this.form1.cityName.value   = ui.item.cityName;
                                        this.form1.streetName.value = ui.item.streetName;

                                     }              
                            });
                    });
                }(jQuery))

    </script>
```

---suggest_address.php---

```
<?php


if(!isset($_POST["term"]))
      exit;


$mysqli = new mysqli('Host or IP', 'User', 'Pass', 'DBName');


if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}else{

    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
}



    if ($result  = $mysqli->query("select zip, prefName, cityName, streetName from zipcode where zip like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['term']) .'%" order by zip asc")) {


        $data = array();


        while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) ){

                $data[] = array(
                    'value'      => $row->zip ,
                    'prefName'   => $row->prefName ,
                    'cityName'   => $row->cityName ,
                    'streetName' => $row->streetName
                );
        }

        echo json_encode($data);
    }


flush();

$mysqli->close();
```

?>

Comment: You seem to have script tags nested inside another script tag. That's not allowed.

Comment: Are you using developer tools? If you press f12 (on firefox & chrome) and navigate to the console tab & start typing, it will show you all the requests you are making. If you could paste the outputted error into your question I /someone will help!

Comment: Place the two file includes before `<script language="JavaScript">`

Answer (score 0):

use **alert** in each section to know where it is breaking.
tell correctly in which line u have problem.
1.check whether the autocomplete is invoked or not

2.print in controller

3.alert the return data(array)

4.use alert in neccesary lines to find the problem